# PowerShell array, loop first row

Tags: arrays, powershell, jagged-arrays

I have a problem with array as following with only one line:

```
$list = @()
$list =  (("ResourceGroup","Vm1"))


$list | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

    write-output $_[0] $_[1]

}
```

If I loop that array with one line, PowerShell prints the first 2 letter of each word. If I put 2 or more row like following:

```
    $list = @()
    $list =  (("ResourceGroup","Vm1"),`
              ("ResourceGroup","Vm2")
)
```

PowerShell print correctly the values inside.

There is a way to print correctly the value of an array with only one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`("ResourceGroup","Vm1")` is interpreted as **one array with two string elements**, where as `(("ResourceGroup","Vm1"), ("ResourceGroup","Vm2"))` is interpreted as **one array with 2 array elements**, can be also called a [*jagged array*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). If you want to ensure that the first example is treated the same as the second example, you can use the [comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-):

```
$list = , ("ResourceGroup","Vm1")
$list | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Write-Output $_[0] $_[1]
}
```

To put it in perspective:

```
$list = ("ResourceGroup","Vm1")
$list[0].GetType() # => String

$list = , ("ResourceGroup","Vm1")
$list[0].GetType() # => Object[]
```

[`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.2) with the [`-NoEnumerate` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.2#example-3-suppress-enumeration-in-output) combined with the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) can be another, *more verbose*, alternative:

```
$list = @(Write-Output "ResourceGroup", "Vm1" -NoEnumerate)
$list | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Write-Output $_[0] $_[1]
}
```